# DialogFragment created by an event from a button in a custom ArrayAdapter always has same position

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, android-dialogfragment

I'm a newb so try to be patient with me

Here is some background information about the problem I am having:

I have a fragment, ViewFragment, that consists of two components: a Spinner and a ListView. The Spinner is a default Spinner with a regular ArrayAdapter that fills the Spinner with values taken from an ArrayList called "metaList" that is basically and ArrayList of objects that each themselves have an ArrayList called "mainList".

The ListView has the custom ArrayAdapter (called "CustomAdapter")  I mentioned in the title. The CustomAdapter fills the ListView with values taken from the "mainList" of the selected item in the Spinner.

Now, the CustomAdapter for the ListView has two buttons. The only button that does anything yet (called "viewButton") creates a DialogFragment when pushed.

The problem I am having relates to this DialogFragment. Each item in the ListView should create a unique DialogFragment when its viewButton is pressed. However, regardless of which item in the ListView has its button pressed, the DialogFragment is always the same and displays the DialogFragment for the last item in the ListView.

I think that this problem is due to the fact that the ListView items themselves are not being pressed, only their buttons, so the position value in the getView() method for the CustomAdapter never really changes.

How do I fix this problem?

Here is the code for the ViewFragment that contains the Spinner and ListView components:

```
package com.statbot;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;

public class ViewFragment extends Fragment{

static int spinPos;
private ArrayList<String> names;
private ArrayList<String> nums;
private Spinner spinner;
private View view;
private ViewGroup container;
private ListView listView;
private Fragment frag;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {    

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_layout, container, false);
    this.container = container;
    frag = this;
    names = new ArrayList<String>();
    nums = new ArrayList<String>();
    spinner = (Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.view_frag_spinner1);
    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.view_frag_listView2);


    for(int k = 0; k < MainActivity.metaList.size(); k++)
    {
        names.add(MainActivity.metaList.get(k).getName());
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>      (container.getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, names);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new SpinListener());

    return view;
}

private class SpinListener extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener{

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
            long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        spinPos = pos;
        nums.clear();
        for(int k = 0; k < MainActivity.metaList.get(pos).mainList.size(); k++)
        {
            nums.add("" + MainActivity.metaList.get(pos).mainList.get(k).quantity);
        }
        CustomAdapter adapter2 = new CustomAdapter(container.getContext(),   android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, nums);
        adapter2.setFrag(frag);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        spinPos = 0;
    }
}
}
```

Here is the code for the CustomAdapter:

```
package com.statbot;

import java.util.List;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{

private TextView quantity;
private ImageButton editButton;
private ImageButton deleteButton;
private ImageButton viewButton;
private Context mContext;
private int id;
private Fragment frag;
private int pos;
private List<String> objects;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public CustomAdapter (Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<String> objects){   
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);    
    mContext = context;
    id = textViewResourceId;
    this.objects = objects;
}   

public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent){
    this.pos = position;
    final int POSITION = position;
    View mView = v;

    if (mView == null){     
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mView = vi.inflate(R.layout.cust_list_view, parent, false);
    }


    editButton = (ImageButton) mView.findViewById(R.id.cust_list_view_button1);
    viewButton = (ImageButton) mView.findViewById(R.id.cust_list_view_button2);
    quantity = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.cust_list_view_textView1);
    if(quantity == null)
    {
        System.out.println("The poop is a lie");
    }
    quantity.setText("" + pos + "," + ViewFragment.spinPos);


    viewButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("" + POSITION);
            showContents(ViewFragment.spinPos, POSITION);
        }

    });

    return mView;
}
private void showContents(int metaPos, int mainPos){
    NumStatDialog contents = new NumStatDialog();
    contents.setMainPosition(pos);
    contents.setMetaPosition();
    contents.show(frag.getFragmentManager(), "content_dialog");
}
public void setFrag(Fragment f){
    frag = f;
}

}
```

Here is the code for the DialogFragment, called NumStatDialog:

```
package com.statbot;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

@SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
public class NumStatDialog extends DialogFragment{

private View view;
private int metaPosition;
private int mainPosition;
private TextView title;
private TextView info;
private boolean type;//if true, sets up a dialog to display information on a list. if false, displays information on an item of that list.


public NumStatDialog(int metaPos, int mainPos){
    type = false;
    metaPosition = metaPos;
    mainPosition = mainPos;
}

public NumStatDialog(int metaPos){
    type = true;
    metaPosition = metaPos;
}
public NumStatDialog(){

}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.numstat_dialog_layout, container);

    info = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.numstat_dialog_textView2);
    title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.numstat_dialog_textView1);
    if(!type){
        //info.setText((CharSequence) MainActivity.metaList.get(metaPosition).mainList.get(mainPosition).toString());
        info.setText((CharSequence) ("" + mainPosition));
        //title.setText((CharSequence) ("" + MainActivity.metaList.get(metaPosition).mainList.get(mainPosition).quantity));
        title.setText((CharSequence) ("" + metaPosition));
    }
    if(type){
        info.setText((CharSequence) MainActivity.metaList.get(metaPosition).toString());
        title.setText((CharSequence) MainActivity.metaList.get(metaPosition).getName());
    }


    return view;
}
public void setMainPosition(int mp){
    mainPosition = mp;
}
public void setMetaPosition(){
    metaPosition = ViewFragment.spinPos;
}
}
```

and here are some screenshots to make things easier to understand. The spinner is at the top with the ListView directly below it. The first number of each ListView item is its position, and the second number is the position of the Spinner. The button of interest is the paper-shaped one. ignore the pencil, it doesn't do anything yet.

[image]

and here is a DialogFragment. The title is the Spinner position and the bottom number is the position of the item whose button was pushed, but notice that even though the 1st item on the ListView had its button pushed to display this dialog, the number at the bottom of the fragment displays a three for the 4th item.

[image]

Any help on this problem would be greatly appreciated, this is one of the last major hurdles I need to overcome for this project, everything else should be pretty basic.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `showContents()`, you completely ignore the two parameters passed in and instead use `this.pos`, which would indeed be the position of the last view inflated by the `ListView`. Just use your parameters (and set up your IDE to warn you about unused variables and parameters).

On a different note, passing data to a fragment like this would not survive configuration changes (unless you have `setRetainInstance` everywhere, but that's riddled with different sorts of problems). Consider using `setArguments`, serializing state in `onSaveInstanceState` and deserializing it in `onCreate` (using `getArguments` or `savedInstanceState`, if that's available).

Comment: wow thanks that turned out to be the only problem. can't believe I made that mistake. I don't really understand the second part of your answer, however. Can you explain what "serializing" is?

Comment: Serializing refers to a unified way of saving and restoring objects. In normal Java, this is done via the Serializable interface. In Android Java, the preferred way is Parcelable and Bundles. 

What I *actually* meant was that you should save your instance variables (i.e., fields) in `onSaveInstanceState` and restore them from `savedInstanceState` in `onCreate`. That way, you know that whatever Android decides to do to your fragment and activity, your state can be consistently saved and restored and you're covered.